# Is there a way to read JSON data inside Custom Fields without editing PHP?

Tags: custom-field, javascript, json

I have a post with `Custom Field` called `json_data`, inside there is an array of strings such as: `{"data":["string no 1","string no 2","string no 3"]}`.

Is there a way to read the data using JavaScript and Elementor without editing the PHP file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use `JSON.parse($string);` to convert your string value to JSON format within Javascript.

```
<script>
    var json_data_string = '{"data":["string no 1","string no 2","string no 3"]}'; // or echo the json_data field as <?php echo $json_data; ?>
    var json_data = JSON.parse(json_data_string);
    // Now access the properties as 
    $data = json_data.data; // outputs: string no 1,string no 2,string no 3
    $string1 = json_data.data[0]; // outputs: string no 1 
</script>
```

[Reference to JSON.parse() function in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the answer. But how I load the `json_data` from the Custom Field?

Comment: Where do you want to load the field data? In the backend or frontend? If backend, where exactly? Like in another metabox?